# Why does this changeset not update correctly with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm following pretty much what pattern we see in a generated controller.  The changeset says it is valid but when I update the User model does not get updated.  The role remains nil.

```
> alias Faq.Repo
> user = Repo.get!(User, 1)
> changeset = User.changeset(user, %{role: 'admin'})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, errors: [], data: #Faq.User<>,
valid?: true>
> Repo.update(changeset)
{:ok,
  %Faq.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
  current_sign_in_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-02 03:54:54>,
  current_sign_in_ip: "{127, 0, 0, 1}", email: "gary.haran@gmail.com", id: 1,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-01 04:18:48>,
  last_sign_in_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-01 04:55:51>,
  last_sign_in_ip: "{127, 0, 0, 1}", name: "Gary Haran", password: nil,
  password_confirmation: nil,
  password_hash: "$2b$12$K603vGmolll/RtaXTrtcsusHbIsXi4IqB9yM9Ph65T3Cqlh/J5UbG",
  reset_password_sent_at: nil, reset_password_token: nil, 
  role: nil,
  sign_in_count: 5, 
  unlock_token: nil,
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-02 03:54:54>}}
```

What am I missing?

/edit Here is my changeset method:

```
  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:name, :email] ++ coherence_fields)
    |> validate_required([:name, :email])
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> validate_coherence(params)
  end
```

Comment: Do you have `role` in the allowed fields in the call to `cast` in `User.changeset/2`?

Comment: you should share the code in your `User.changeset/2` function.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any reason you are using a char list for the role and not a string? Not sure if that would have an impact on your changeset but generally not something that would be used unless you are passing it to erlang for example.

Comment: @GaryHaran What is the value of `coherence_fields`? If it doesn't contain `:role`, you need to add it there or to the `[:name, :email]` list. Also, like @Stuart said, if it's a string column in the database, you need to use a string instead of char list (double quotes instead of single).

Comment: @Dogbert indeed I did not have `:role` in the fields.  Thanks to you and @stuart I also learned something valuable here about single versus double quotes.